# How to visualize the outgoing directions sampled from BSDF?

Tags: rendering, brdf, bsdf

I'm trying to find a way to visualize the outgoing directions sampled from BSDF.

More specifically, for a given incident direction, I can sample the outgoing directions, using 'BSDF sample', and I want to visualize them. I tried to output some images but they have low quality. Does anyone know how to visualize those outgoing directions? Is there any software researchers often use for a case like this? Or some API? Or something else? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Maybe this would be relevant: https://github.com/wdas/brdf